# AngularJS $sce.trustAsHtml() on heavily tagged data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know $sce.trustAsHtml() works for having AngularJS show HTML as-is.  After some fidgeting, I've realized this doesn't work in all cases.  Specifically when that data has other  tags in it.

If I'm using simple HTML tags (br, b etc.,) it works fine. However, I have quite a few rows of data that look like this:

```
<div class="question">This is question1</div>
<div class="answer"> this is an answer1</div>
<div class="question">This is question2</div>
<div class="answer"> this is an answer2</div>
```

An entry above is an example of a text column in a MySQL databases.  Doing the following, Angular moans:

Javascript:

```
$http.get(site_url).success(function(response) {
    $scope.textClean = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.text);
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="box" ng-bind-html="textClean"></div>
```

I've tried storing it in other tags, but no dice.  Any ideas for a viable workaround?  Surely Angular can handle this.  If I remove the tags, it displays, but of course, w/o the traits that are needed.

EDIT: WOW - what an oversight on my part.  Okay, I figured out the issue.  I'm getting data from the MySQL DB via a PHP script.  PHP spits it out in JSON format.  Since class contains quotation marks, it's in $http.get() part that the error is occuring... not in the printing.  I had done some debugging that lead me to believe otherwise, but clearly I was wrong.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: What error are you getting

Comment: Sorry for not posting it.  It was a rather cryptic one.  Basically said, "unexpected character 'X'" or something to that effect, where X is the first letter of the value of the property of the div that Angular didn't like.  Either class or style, in my limited test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tEL9rVQmzL1A1gBFpUpN?p=preview), showing

```
<div class="question">This is question1</div>
<div class="answer"> this is an answer1</div>
<div class="question">This is question2</div>
<div class="answer"> this is an answer2</div>
```

can be parsed via $sce.trurstAsHtml()

If your response contains any angular directive, then that angular directive will not work. For that you need to use $compile service.

Comment: Thanks, will check this tonight when I'm home.

Comment: Close enough -- it got me open my eyes and see the issue. ;)